# vector vs raster graphic in movies

Tags: 3d, photoshop, unity-game-engine, vector-graphics, 3dsmax

I have a question that in today's movies like Kung fu panda,Rio etc,Is there vector Images involved or raster one?How can we get information about these movies that how they developed them?Anyone who can help me with this..
**Note :i am tagging people from different fields who had command on graphics**

Comment: Kung Fu Panda, and Rio both use 3d models for their graphics, I'm not sure what you mean by vector images or raster images. Also this question is off-topic, it's not about programming at all.

Comment: @thedaian 3d models are developed in which software?is the image raster or vector?

Comment: @user1115580 Usually in specialised 3d modelling software like 3d Studio Max. Which isn't raster or vector.

Comment: Off-topic; and they're rasterised 3d scenes achieved by solving the rendering equation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes these movies used vector graphics because if you zoom in the image remain crisp,you can get info from the company website only

Comment: Ironic that this has been accepted because its not right!  But then the question will be closed in about 5 minutes and then later deleted